# How do I show a plotted graph on R Markdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I have created a parabola but I would like to show my work using R Markdown. I have put in the procedure as follows:

`{r}
plot( function(x) 352 - 352*x + 91*(x^2))`

`{r}
p <- polynomial(c(-10,-3,1))`

`{r}
plot(p, xlab="Beta", ylab="Sum of Squares")`

I feel like I am doing it correctly but when I open the HTML document, it just shows a blue icon with a question mark in the middle (similar to when you open a browser but can't view the photo). Anybody Help?

Comment: Use RStudio, and open a Markdown document, there is a clear example.

Answer (score 0):

But here it is:

````
```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6} 
plot(cars)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have just forgot to call your library (you didn't mention it in the above):

````
```{r}
library(polynom)
p <- polynomial(c(-10,-3,1))
plot(p, xlab="Beta", ylab="Sum of Squares")
```
````